# SoftKey comes over the Edittext -- Android

Tags: android, textbox, keyboard

I am developing an Android application. When focus comes over one of the EditText(at lower end of page) the keypad covers the EditText so when I am keying text, I can't see what's being keyed in. What are my options ?

How to move EditText higher on the screen ?

I have tried 
`<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
</activity>`

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
```

Here is the code

```
FrameLayout container =  (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.Container);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    RelativeLayout setRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, null);
    container.addView(setRelativeLayout);
```

This doesn't work for me.

Comment: adjustpan doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: Try wrapping a ScrollView around the layout containing the EditText (or the entire layout) making sure the top of the ScrollView is above the area that the keypad covers.

Comment: @NigelK Scrollbar is also not working. Its giving error on RelativeLayout setRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, null);

Comment: I wasn't aware you were inflating programmatically. Remove the scrollview from the layout. Create a ScrollView in code, add the RelativeLayout you inflate to it and then use/return/set the ScrollView instead of the RelativeLayout. If that makes no sense (I'm only guessing what your code looks like) please post some code to give your question some more context.

Comment: Use scroll view in your layout..

Comment: @Subburaj scroll view in layout doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that adjustResize and adjustPan do not work for you suggests that your layout fills the screen and Android is unable to adjust it to make space for the keypad. If however your layout is contained within a scrollview, that may resolve the issue.

You currently inflate a RelativeLayout and add that to a FrameLayout. I suggest you instead try creating a ScrollView, adding the RelativeLayout to it and then adding the ScrollView to the FrameLayout:

```
FrameLayout container =  (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.Container);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
RelativeLayout setRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, null);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
sv.addView(setRelativeLayout);
container.addView(sv);
```

Comment: Its working in small screens as it was already working in it but in bigger screens like S3,the editext itself raises itself even by adding scrollview